# Django REST Framework -- destroy method won't take on URL params?

Tags: python, django, rest, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am designing an API endpoint using Django REST Framework, and would like for it to accept GET and POST methods at the following endpoint:

```
companies/<company_pk>/membership
```

as well as DELETE methods at the following endpoint:

```
companies/<company_pk>/membership/<membership_pk>
```

There are two relevant models: `Company` and `CompanyMembership`. Each user can be a member of one or more companies,which is represented by an instance of `CompanyMembership`, which linked by a FK to `Company`.

I've created the appropriate GET and POST requests, but am having trouble with the DELETE requests -- it seems that the `destroy` method within my view is missing the `membership_pk` parameter, whether or not I define it within my URLs. How can I have my view accept DELETE requests which delete instances of `CompanyMembership`, which are identified by the `membership_pk` given in the URL?

```
urls.py

...
    url(r'^companies/(?P<company_pk>[0-9]+)/membership', include(company_urls.company_membership_router.urls,
        namespace='company_memberships')),
...

views.py


class CompanyMembershipViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A ViewSet for creating, retrieving, and deleting CompanyMemberships.
    """
    queryset = CompanyMembership.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanyMembershipSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'company_pk'

    def get_queryset(self):
        uid = self.kwargs.get(self.lookup_url_kwarg)
        memberships = CompanyMembership.objects.filter(company_id=uid)
        return memberships

    def create(self, request, company_pk):
        """
        Custom create method since company_pk does not have to be sent
        explicitly within request.data

        Returns: instance of rest_framework Response.
        """
        EXISTING_USER_ERROR = {'non_field_errors':
            ['The fields user, company must make a unique set.']
        }
        data = {
            'user': request.data['user'],
            'company': company_pk
        }
        serializer = CompanyMembershipSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        if serializer.errors == EXISTING_USER_ERROR:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=settings.ADDITIONAL_HTTP_STATUS_CODES['422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY'])
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def destroy(self, request, **kwargs):
        company_membership = self.get_object(pk=membership_pk)
        company_membership.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)


routers.py
    from rest_framework import routers

    from .views import CompanyViewSet, CompanyMembershipViewSet


    company_router = routers.DefaultRouter()
    company_membership_router = routers.DefaultRouter()

    company_router.register(r'^', CompanyViewSet)
    company_membership_router.register(r'^', CompanyMembershipViewSet)
```

Comment: where is your `membership_pk` defined in your destroy method? Do you mean `kwargs['membership_pk']`

Comment: @dnit13 yeah so that's my question exactly -- when I add a break statement and look in kwargs for the `destroy` method, there is no `membership_pk`, even though the URL I am sending the `POST` request with is `companies/10/membership/3` -- so there's clearly a `membership_pk` that should be being passed somehow -- I'm just not sure why the `destroy` method can't access it. I suspect that I am setting up my URLs wrong perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The company membership router generates the following urls:

```
companies/<company_pk>/membership/ # for handling list requests
companies/<company_pk>/membership/<pk>/ # for handling detail requests
```

You can access the `membership_pk` **using the `pk` url kwarg .**

Also, you have incorrectly defined `lookup_url_kwarg` field in your viewset. This `kwarg` is used by DRF to retrieve the object using `get_object()` method. You are not getting object because it is trying to perform lookup with `pk` as `company_pk` url kwarg value instead of `pk` value.

Comment: thanks. Managed to look it up by removing `lookup_url_kwarg` and looking up the object by using `Membership.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))`